# Auto size height for rows in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am inputting values into a spreadsheet using Apache POI. These values have newlines, and I was able to use this code successfully:

```
CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle()
style.setWrapText(true)
cell.setCellStyle(style)
```

Unfortunately, while the text is wrapping correctly, the rows are not always growing in height enough to show the content. How do I ensure that my rows are always the correct height?

Answer (score 32):

```
currentRow.setHeight((short)-1)
```

Works for XSSFCell and Excel 2013

Comment: Shockingly, this also worked in NPOI (the .NET implementation) and opens correctly in Excel 2013. Syntax is slightly different: `row.Height = -1;`

Comment: This solution does not work for Ubuntu's LibreOffice version 5.1.6.2 and POI 3.17, but it does work if document is opened with MSExcel

Comment: Exactly the good answer!

Answer (score 22):

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  
HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setWrapText(true);
row.setRowStyle(style);
row.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
```

The above code will generate dynamic height of rows.

Comment: `style.setWrapText(true)` was enough. Thanks!

Comment: Eee...no this does not work. At least not on Ubuntu Linux with Libre Office

Comment: @ed22, doesn't work for me as well. Same environment.

Comment: This is a Libre Office related issue. Spreadsheet opens correctly in MS Excel

Comment: I also have to use Libre Office and this doesn't solve the row height problem. Is there any way to make Libre Office display better row heights? I have a cell with a slightly bigger font in it. Libre Office doesn't increase the row height automatically, whereas MS Office and Open Office increase the height in a nice way.

Comment: style.setWrapText(true) was enough in my case! There are merged cells present.

Comment: doesn't work with MS Office 365

Comment: Hi wraps the text for cells do not have new line as well. How to wrap the text only for cell contain new line?

Answer (score 5):

The only way I got this to work was write my own implementation to calculate the row height. The code is now released as the [Taro](https://github.com/jbrundege/taro/wiki) project, so you could use that. It has numerous convenience methods to let you write an Excel file in far fewer lines of code.

If you prefer to put the implementation in your own code, you can find it in the [SpreadsheetTab](https://github.com/jbrundege/taro/blob/master/src/main/java/taro/spreadsheet/model/SpreadsheetTab.java) class. There is an autoSizeRow(int rowIndex) method half way down. It basically iterates down the row and for each cell finds the number of lines of text, then uses the font size to calculate the optimal cell height. It then sets the row height to the height of the tallest cell.

Comment: Note: This only works with cells that have `\n` on their values. You have to determine where to place the `\n` on your own. If there is none, the row will have one line height

Answer (score 4):

See all [this link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200906.mbox/%3C24216153.post@talk.nabble.com%3E), which provides some code to manually calculate the correct height for a row, based on the column width and cell content. I've not personally tested it. Also pasted below for convenience:

```
// Create Font object with Font attribute (e.g. Font family, Font size, etc) for calculation
java.awt.Font currFont = new java.awt.Font(fontName, 0, fontSize);
AttributedString attrStr = new AttributedString(cellValue);
attrStr.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, currFont);

// Use LineBreakMeasurer to count number of lines needed for the text
FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(attrStr.getIterator(), frc);
int nextPos = 0;
int lineCnt = 0;
while (measurer.getPosition() < cellValue.length())
{
    nextPos = measurer.nextOffset(mergedCellWidth); // mergedCellWidth is the max width of each line
    lineCnt++;
    measurer.setPosition(nextPos);
}

Row currRow = currSht.getRow(rowNum);
currRow.setHeight((short)(currRow.getHeight() * lineCnt));

// The above solution doesn't handle the newline character, i.e. "\n", and only
// tested under horizontal merged cells.
```

Comment: The last line must use either: row.getHeightInPoints() or currSht.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints() instead of "getHeight()"

Answer (score 3):

In my case a robust solution was to calculate the number of lines and set the row height to a multiple of the default row height:

```
int numberOfLines = cell.getStringCellValue().split("\n").length;
row.setHeightInPoints(numberOfLines*sheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints());
```

Comment: pointless since you get this even without new lines

Answer (score 2):

```
cell.getRow().setHeight((short) -1);
```

Worked for HSSFCell in apache poi 3.9 or above

Answer (score 1):

It works in Excel 2010.
 I set the limit of cell length of 50 characters

```
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setWrapText(true);
    if (data.length() > 50) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.abs(data.length() / 50); i++) {
            data = data.substring(0, i * 50) + "\n" + data.substring(i * 50);
        }
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        row.setRowStyle(style);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        cell.setCellValue(data);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
    }
```

Comment: sooo no auto height

Answer (score 0):

You can't adjust cell height directly.
But you can change the row's height

```
final HSSFSheet fs = wb.createSheet("sheet1");
final HSSFRow row0 = fs.createRow(0);
final HSSFCell cellA1 = row0.createCell(0);
row0.setHeight((short)700);
```

Comment: This is not automatic sizing (auto-size), it is manual sizing.

Answer (score -1):

Row aitosize work for me:

```
cell.getRow().setHeight((short)0);
```

Here `0` for calculate autoheight.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. When I open in Excel (2010), the row is simply zero height.

Comment: @GreenGiant, I don't use Windows and Excel. This solution work for OpenOffice. Also it problem to set automatically row height for `merged` cells in Excel ([need macro](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/06/07/autofit-merged-cell-row-height/) for fix it).

Comment: Sadly, this will set to zero heigh a.k.a invisible

Comment: value -1 actually worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Workaround for “LibreOffice Calc“ and “WPS Spreadsheet” with auto height for merged sells.

I add a column out to the right of a main document (In my case it was 32 column)
Set width as all merged cells with same text.
Set style WrapText to true
Set style to Align Top
Copy content which will be displayed in the merged cells
Set that column to be hidden
Set a row height = -1

A sample of code:

```
   private void applyRowHightWorkaroundForMergedCells(HSSFCell cell0) {
       HSSFSheet sheet = cell0.getSheet();
       HSSFRow row = cell0.getRow();
    
       String value = cell0.getStringCellValue();
       HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(32);
       sheet.setColumnWidth(32, 32000);
       cell.getCellStyle().setWrapText(true);
       cell.getCellStyle().setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
       cell.setCellValue(value);
       sheet.setColumnHidden(32, true);
       row.setHeight((short) -1);
   }
```

Answer (score -11):

//we can use column width for sheet

```
Ex: sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 2000);
```

Comment: The OP is asking about adjusting row height not column width.