# How to auto-size height of merged rows in HSSFSheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a merged rows inside HSSFSheet [image: sheet with merged rows]
And I trying to set row's height automatically this way:

```
 borderedStyle.setWrapText(true);
 row.setHeight((short)-1);
```

whole code is here https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/ad3011adb78d6d16d7b6a15d2db7fbd3
It works fine for some rows but not for merged ones. Please help me to auto-size for example tenth row.
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744922/apache-poi-and-auto-row-height-with-merged-cells